# Domain object behavior how to

Tags: java, object, dns

Here's a rather dumb but perfectly valid question coming from a newbie. 
Context: My "domain object" has a name (and some other attributes, but they are not important). This name is generated according to some patterns which are defined in the database.
Now... who should determine the name of the domain object? Should the domain object determine it's own name (please note this "name" can be based on it's own or some other object's attributes) or should a service determine the name according to the pattern and then call something like

```
domainObject.setName(theActualName)
```

I tend to follow the "service" approach, but on the other hand it seems this task should be an object-specific behaviour.

Thanks a lot for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look at [Tell Don't Ask Principle](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask)

If object contains all the data it needs to calculate its name I would put this method on that class. If this data is based on other object's attributes and parent class also contains this child object that contains data, I would again put on the parent class.

Just Keep it simple. I wouldn't introduce a service class if I dont really need. In DDD terms you should put your domain related logic in domain classes .

Answer (score 1):

This is a domain object that contains logic? If yes, I'd rather give it a reference to DAO and let it decide its name on its own. In this way your logic will be near your data.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues bear on this:

1. Do you need some sort of management of the names? (An example would be a directory to look up an object by name.) If so, consider using a service. (An alternative would be to arrange for each domain object to register itself once it figures out its name.)
2. Are the domain objects logically independent of the data base once they have been created and names? If so, then it would be good practice to keep them independent by putting the data base dependence in a service.

If the domain objects are going to be tied to the data base anyway, and if there is no need to centrally manage the names, then I would think that having the domain objects name themselves leads toward greater [object cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: Let me get some things clear(er) - the general workflow looks like this: the user enters some data in a form, uploads a file and then this whole thing gets saved in a content management system (think EMC Documentum, or Sharepoint). The domain object is actually the data that the user enters + the content + some other attributes that are determined based on different conditions - lifecycle stage, object name, object security etc.